# How to compare numbers and return the highest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I compare `primaryCurrencyAmount` in the array and return the highest numbers to lowest?

```js
const cryptoCoin = [
  {name: 'BTC', amount: 1.4, primaryCurrencyAmount: 1233},
  {name: 'ETH', amount: 10.3, primaryCurrencyAmount: 8000},
  {name: 'USDT', amount: 5, primaryCurrencyAmount: 5125},
  {name: 'LTC', amount: 7, primaryCurrencyAmount: 1400},
];
```

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort based on `primaryCurrencyAmount`

```
cryptoCoin.sort((a,b)=>  b.primaryCurrencyAmount - a.primaryCurrencyAmount)
```